# (T) cast in Java

Tags: java, generics

How does Java generic (T) (exactly in form of the typecast operator) cast work? As I understand it at this moment, type erasure wipes out substituted type to Object or upper bound anyway and it will be the cast to Object or to a certain supertype of T. So what's the point then?

Comment: I think it's just something that the compiler analyzes statically and asserts is correct.  Do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: Is the question about what are generic types for? If so it's all about compile type correctness.

Comment: The point is to make the code compile.

Comment: It is a common pattern in my company to use the _recursive generics_ pattern: `public class Thing<T extends Thing<T>> { public T doStuff() { // some business logic code return (T) this; } }` Why does this cast work? Erasuse definition claims T will be wiped out to upper bound in this case, so `Ball extends Thing<Ball>` has to have `(Thing<Ball>) this`, but `get()` returns **Ball** perfectly... kinda magic.

Comment: Not much magic about it as `this` is a `Ball`—which is a `Thing`—at that point. According to [§4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) of the _JLS_ that should actually resolve to `(Thing) this`. That said, your example code should be emitting a compilation warning saying `(T) this` is unchecked/unsafe. Consider the following: `class Bat extends Thing<Ball> {}`. That's perfectly valid code but will now cause invocations of `bat.doStuff()` to throw `ClassCastException`s.